# You have 6 red balls, 6 blue, and 6 white. You randomly select a sample of 3 balls without replacement.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You have 6 red balls, 6 blue, and 6 white. You randomly select a sample of 3 balls without replacement. The balls, save for the color, are indistinguishable from each other. What are the odds that your sample contains at least a ball from each color?

I thought about finding the chance that the sample will not contain at least one color and subtracting that from one:

$$P(\text{sample is missing at least one color})=P(\text{sample is missing one color})+P(\text{sample is missing two colors}) $$

Essentially the second probability statement on the right hand side is the probability that all the balls in the sample are the same color. The case where the sample does not contain three colors doesn't make sense, so I didn't include it.
$$=\binom{3}{1} \left[\left(\frac{12}{18}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{11}{17}\right) \cdot\left(\frac{10}{16}\right)\right]+\binom{3}{2}\left[\left(\frac{6}{18}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{5}{17}\right) \cdot\left(\frac{4}{16}\right)\right] \approx 0.882353$$

When all of this is done, we simply subtract the probability from one to get $0.117647$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**  We find the probability that the three balls are each of a different color.

There are $\binom{18}{3}$ ways to select a subset of three of the eighteen balls.  From these, we select one of six blue balls, one of six white balls, and one of six white balls.  Hence, the probability that the three balls we select are each of a different color is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$

**Method 2:**  We find the probability that at least one color is missing and subtract that from $1$.

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to exclude one of the colors and $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to select three of the remaining twelve balls.

However, we have counted those selections in which all the balls are of the same color twice, once for each of the ways we could exclude one of the other two colors.  Since we only want to exclude these selections once, we must add the number of selections in which only one color is selected.  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to exclude two colors and $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select three balls of the remaining color.

Hence, the probability that at least one color is missing is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{12}{3} - \dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$
Subtracting this from $1$ gives the probability that a ball of each color is selected.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you do it if your sample was bigger (like five, for example)? How would you take care of the last two balls in the sample that can be of any color?

Comment: There are $\binom{18}{5}$ ways to select five balls.  There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to exclude one color and $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to select five balls from the remaining two colors.  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to exclude two of the three colors.  There are $\binom{6}{5}$ ways to select five balls of the remaining color.  Hence, the number of selections of five balls that contain at least one ball of each color is $$\binom{18}{5} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{12}{5} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{6}{5}$$  Divide this by $$\binom{18}{5}$$ to obtain the desired probability.

Answer (score 0):

Notice in your formula 
$$P(\text{sample will not contain at least one color})$$
$$=P(\text{sample doesn't contain one color})$$$$+P(\text{sample doesn't contain two colors}) $$

The two probability you try to decompose are not mutually exclusive.

sample doesn't contain one color: contains two colors or $\color{red}{\text{three colors}}$.

sample doesn't contain two colors: contains one color or $\color{red}{\text{three colors}}$.

**EDIT**

I'll provide a method that follows exactly the intended/original carve-out of the OP.

$$P(\text{sample is missing contain one color})$$
$$=P(\text{sample has exactly two colors})$$
$$=\frac{\dbinom{3}{2}\times \dbinom{2}{1} \times \dbinom{6}{1} \times \dbinom{6}{2}}{\dbinom{18}{3}} $$

$$P(\text{sample is missing two colors})$$
$$=P(\text{sample has exactly one colors})$$
$$=\frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\times \dbinom{6}{3}}{\dbinom{18}{3}} $$

Comment: If your sample doesn't contain one color, how can it contain three?

Comment: @Q.Araham I think there might be some wording differences.. what do you mean by "sample does not contain one color"? My understanding is that the three balls you get are not all in the same color.

Comment: Your sample contains two colors. I should've said that. Let me fix it. The three balls you get don't necessarily have to be the same color. $P(\text{sample contains two colors})$ represents the probability that your sample is made up of three balls of only two colors (i.e. one ball one color, two balls another color).

Comment: @Q.Araham are you sure your update make sense?

Comment: @Q.Araham for example, {sample contains two colors} should be the compliment set of {sample doesn't contain two colors}, unless you have your own definition about your wording.

Comment: Sorry, I had edited the wrong probability statements. Should be good now.

Comment: @Q.Araham Your edit is still wrong. sample does not contain at least one color would have probability of $0$. I think you are confused about carving out events. Try to have an example for each event you describe, and I think it'll help you. But it is a good try/practice for you.

Comment: I see. I edited it once more. Examples: One color missing—You have two red balls and one blue ball. You're missing white. Two colors missing—You have three red balls. You're missing blue and white. I don't believe the probability of the sample missing at least one color is zero, is it?

Comment: @Q.Araham great, now you get it, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Did you update it or is it just my browser not working?

Comment: @Q.Araham Sorry, I need to get out. Will get back to you tomorrow..

Comment: Really quickly, do you have the answer?

Comment: Thanks. This is for the $P(\text{sample is missing at least one color})$, right?

Comment: @Q.Araham Updated. Sorry for the late reply, there is already an answer, hope I could provide another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Your probability for the 2 color case is wrong. To have one color missing, you need to have one of the next two draws not match the first one (12 ways) and one of them match (5 ways), or to have them match each other but not the first (12 ways for the second and 5 ways for the third). This gives
$$
P(\mathrm{1\;color\;missing}) = 3\frac{12\cdot 5}{17\cdot 16} = \frac{45}{68}
$$

Comment: Is the other probability correct?

Comment: Yes it is, though it's kind of an odd way to write it.

Comment: What would be a more conventional way of writing it?

Comment: Eh, nvm, it's fine.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, don't be shy ;)